# equalTo validation with jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Below is my form which has password and confirm password field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">password</label>               
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" 
          data-validate="minlength[8]" 
                 data-message-required="email is required" placeholder="password">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">confirm password</label>               
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password_confirm" 
       data-validate="minlength[8],equalTo[password]" 
          data-message-required="email is required" placeholder="confirm password">
</div>
```

Below is my part of validation field.

```
if (params = rule.match(/(\w+)\[(.*?)\]/i)) {
    if ($.inArray(params[1], ['minlength', 'equalTo']) != -1) {
        opts['rules'][name][params[1]] = params[2];
        message = $field.data('message-' + params[1]);
        if (message) {
            opts['messages'][name][params[1]] = message;
        }
    }
 }
```

The `minlength[8]` seems to work perfectly, but when i try to match my `password` with confirm password its not working. I tried passing the name attribute in three ways, but none of them work.

```
 equalTo[password]
 equalTo["password"]
 equalTo["#password"]
```

Also can anyone tell me what does this regular expression do `/(\w+)\[(.*?)\]/i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter inside `equalTo["#password"]` is `#password`.

`#password` is a jQuery selector that matches an element with `id="password"`.  However, I don't see a `id` attribute on your `password` field.  Try adding one...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" ....
```

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"Also can anyone tell me what does this regular expression do `/(\w+)\[(.*?)\]/i`"*

See: http://regexr.com/39d43